# Need help using a mutator function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I need to use a mutator method to change elements of a list in Python. I would normally do this using a function that can return a value, but for this assignment we are not allowed to return any values in the function.

Here's an example of the general idea that i'm talking about

```
def changeX(x):
    x = 5

x = 3
changeX(x)
print(x)
```

The output for this would obviously be 3 since I did not change x.

So my question is, how would I approach this assignment? I need to use the mutator method to modify my variable but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

You get the results you do because you pass a primitive value into your "mutator" function.

If you pass in a list, you'll see that you can change the value in place:

```
def changeX(x):
    x[0]=3

x = [1,2,3]
changeX(x)
print (x)
```

It will print [3,2,3]. Check it out:

https://repl.it/EIZW/0